# What is a simple idiom using Cro to add (eg) `.html` to a static route?

Tags: cro

I want to test a website locally before uploading the html files to a server, where they will sit behind Apache with the following in a VirtualHost configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC]
```

The files to be served all have .html extensions, eg.,

```
rendered/
   one.html
   index.html
   two.html
```

Suppose I use

```
my $app = route {
        get -> *@path {
            static 'rendered', @path,:indexes( 'index.html', );
        }
    }
```

Assuming CroApp is activated with port 5000,
and I try to view `localhost:5000/one`
I get, as I would expect, a 404.

So how do I mimic the Apache rewrite in a natural way?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is:

```
my $app = route {
   get -> *@path {
      @path[*-1] ~= ".html" 
         unless @path[0] eq '' 
                or ("rendered/" ~ @path.join('/')).IO ~~ :e & :f;
         static 'rendered', @path,:indexes( 'index.html', );
      }
   }
```

Comment: I have discovered this does not work for an empty route. `index.html` is not being served if route is ''